# Skype4Py will not attach to Skype on windows

Tags: python, skype, skype4py

i am using a 32 bit python to run it on my win 8 machine, when i run the program skype is responding with a message (seen in the top bar) : "Another application (python.exe) is attempting to access Skype , but we are unable to respond. Please try to restart the application"

Code:

```
import Skype4Py
import socket
import codecs
import sys
#setup
#sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 65205)
#print  'starting up on '+ str(server_address[1])
#sock.bind(server_address)
#sock.listen(1)
#enableling different languages 
UTF8Writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')
sys.stdout = UTF8Writer(sys.stdout)
#skype setup
skype =Skype4Py.Skype()
availFriends = []
skype.Attach()

#block mode
def mstat(Message,status):
    if(status == Skype4Py.cmsReceived ):#act on receive
        Message.MarkAsSeen()
        print Message.Body
        skype.SendMessage(Message.Sender.Handle,"Did you send me :\n"+Message.Body+"\n good , Stop messaging me!")

def GetAllOnlinePeople():
    availFriends = []
    badStatusCodes = ['UNKNOWN', 'OFFLINE', 'DND', 'LOGGEDOUT']
    for f in skype.Friends:
        if not f.OnlineStatus in badStatusCodes:
            availFriends.append(f)


###########################################3
#connection, client_address = sock.accept()
#print  'connection from'+ str(client_address[0])
# Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it    
#data = connection.recv(128)
#if data== 'bmode':
skype.OnMessageStatus = mstat
while(1==1):
    i='p'
```

Comment: Might it be related to https://github.com/Skype4Py/Skype4Py/issues/66?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this would help, but recently I've seen the similar message form skype while I was trying to start [sevabot](https://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) from Windows PowerShell.
Pls, see the screenshot below:
[image]

As soon as I launched it from windows cmd, that alert has gone.
My Skype version is 7.16.85.102 and Skype4Py version is 1.0.35.

Hope that helps.